# "Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing login in react, the test is passing but this error is happening

`Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden`

I already searched and didn't find anything about it in react, only in node

```js
it('make login', async () => {
server.use(
    rest.post('http://localhost:2001/backend_ihm/auth/login', async (req, res, ctx) => {
        const { username, password, keepLogin } = await req.json();
        return res(
            ctx.json(user)
        );
    }));

const { getByTestId } = render(
    <Router>
        <AuthProvider>
            <Login />
        </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
);

await screen.getByTestId('loading');

await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByTestId(/loading/i));

await screen.getByTestId('login-container');

const buttonLogin = getByTestId('button-login');
const checkboxKeepLogin = getByTestId('f');

const { inputUsername, inputPassword } = setup();

fireEvent.change(inputUsername, { target: { value: 'iplabs' } });
fireEvent.change(inputPassword, { target: { value: '123' } });

fireEvent.click(checkboxKeepLogin);
fireEvent.click(buttonLogin);

});
```

Comment: did you mention port number in url?

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:2001/backend_ihm/auth/login

Comment: Why aren't you mocking the API request?

Comment: I'm mocking using msw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to my api file

`axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');`

Answer (score 0):

I see you use JEST JS.

As it is refered here : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1754

It visibly comes from JEST's default environment.

Add this to your jest.config.js file : 
{
"testEnvironment": "node"

}

Comment: do i need to create a jest config file in react? because when we create the project it doesn't come by default

Comment: Refering to JEST's documentation, it looks like developers are expected to create their own config file. "It is recommended to define the configuration in a dedicated JavaScript, TypeScript or JSON file. The file will be discovered automatically, if it is named jest.config.js|ts|mjs|cjs|json"    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Comment: I added this code to my api file and it worked axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');

Comment: Ok, glad you made it work.